# SQL query not showing all the column data

Tags: php, mysql

I got problem with php code. I am trying to get all the data from sql database but its not showing me the fee column. Its showing all other data from all other column.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "stu_data");

/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT id, degree, fee FROM degree";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["id"], $row["degree"], $row["fee"]);
    }

    /* free result set */
    $result->free();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: you have only 2 `%s` in printf. and why dont you just use echo like the rest of us

Comment: You're missing a `%s` in the print parameter list (3 parameters = 3 `%`)

Comment: @JoshKisb how we can use echo here. Can you please help me, actually I am new to php so I don't know much about it.

Comment: @xander it works. Thanks

Comment: @JoshKisb How we can enter this data into HTML table.?

Comment: @Sid use echo like `echo $row["id"]."  (".$row["degree"].") ".$row["fee"];` i actually prefer to first save them in a variable and run htmlentities on them first

Comment: @Sid see my answer below for outputting a table

Comment: Or try this to generate a dynamic table row based on your query: `echo '<tr>' . implode(array_map(function($e) { return "<td>$e</td>"; }, $row)) . '</tr>';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["id"], $row["degree"], $row["fee"]);
}
```

Should be:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    printf ("%s (%s, %s)\n", $row["id"], $row["degree"], $row["fee"]);
}
```

You have 2 %s with 3 variables, so you forgot one.

**Updated to view in table:**

```
<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "stu_data");

    /* check connection */
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
        exit();
    }

    $query = "SELECT id, degree, fee FROM degree";

    if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

        /* fetch associative array */
        echo "<table>";
        echo "<tr><th>ID</th><th>Degree</th><th>Fee</th></tr>";
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            printf ("<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>", $row["id"], $row["degree"], $row["fee"]);
        }
        echo "</table>";

        /* free result set */
        $result->free();
    }

    /* close connection */
    $mysqli->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      echo  "ID: ".$row["id"]." DEGREE: ".$row["degree"]." FEE: ".$row["fee"];
    }
```

You had two $s in printf, as the number one comment stated. Use echo instead of printf.

Comment: For debugging I'd just prefer `var_dump($row)` or `print_r($row)`: Try that and see for yourself.

Comment: @xander yes, i would also consider using print_r but for the OP i wanted to state how to use echo as you can see he is new.

Comment: How we can enter this data into table with column.? Like we have ID, Degree and Fee Column .

Comment: @Sid you can echo the HTML part.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing third format parameter in your `printf` function. Try to add one more `%s` parameter

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "stu_data");

/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT id, degree, fee FROM degree";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      printf ("ID:%s, degree:(%s), fee:%s\n", $row["id"], $row["degree"], $row["fee"]);
    }

    /* free result set */
    $result->free();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```